# Object key-value map reversal

Tags: javascript, hash-map

I have implemented functions that will let me reverse a one-to-many value 'Map', that is a plain JavaScript object.

For example,

```
var map = {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 'bar', 'moo': 'zoo'};
```

becomes

```
var reversedMap = {'zoo': ['moo'], 'bar': ['foo', 'baz']}
```

and also a function to bring back reversed map to a non-reversed map.

[Here's a jsbin to show that my solution is working](http://jsbin.com/luboti/2/edit?js,console).

In the following code I have used lo-dash utility toolbelt, **but you need not be acquainted with it in order to understand the code**. Assume that I trust in performance of lo-dash and what I'm trying to optimize is my own code.

Just for sake of clarity, `_.forOwn` iterates over object's own properties, and `_.forEach` iterates over each element of an array.

```
var identity = function(x) {return x;};
var reverseMapFromMap = function(map, callback) {
    callback = callback || identity; //callback helps to parseInt numeric values, otherwise every object key is a string by default
    var reversedMap = {};
    _.forOwn(map, function(value, key) {
        key = callback(key);
        if (_.isUndefined(reversedMap[value]))
            reversedMap[value] = [key];
        else
            reversedMap[value].push(key);
    });
    return reversedMap;
};

var mapFromReverseMap = function(reverseMap, callback) {
    callback = callback || identity;
    var map = {};
    _.forOwn(reverseMap, function(revMembers, revKey) {
        _.forEach(revMembers, function(revMember) {
            map[revMember] = callback(revKey);
        });
    });
    return map;
};
```

I'm pretty confident in my solution as it's quite basic, but as it is a frequent part of my code, I'd like to know if you can see any ways to improve performance, or alternatively if there's a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: Note that JS has evolved since question was asked and you can now do with native functions: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(hash).map(entry => entry.reverse()))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is pretty good as-is. There are other ways to do the same thing, but yours is fine.

One thing I noticed is that you've skipped braces on the `if...else` in `reverseFromMap`. My advice is to *always* use braces, even for one-line expressions.

However, you could also do

```
reversedMap[value] || (reversedMap[value] = []);
reversedMap[value].push(key);
```

You can collapse that into 1 line, although it's a little *too* terse if you ask me

```
(reversedMap[value] || (reversedMap[value] = [])).push(key);
// or 
(reversedMap[value] = reversedMap[value] || []).push(key);
```

Or just reduce it to a ternary

```
reversedMap[value] ? reversedMap[value].push(key) : reversedMap[value] = [key];
```

The `_.isUndefined` check isn't really required, since `reversedMap[key]` is either a non-empty array, or it's false'y.

Other small stuff:

- I'd prefer the name `iterator` instead of `callback`, but lo-dash uses `callback` in similar situations, so sticking with that convention is fine.
- You don't necessarily need the `identity` function, as you could also do

  ```
  x = callback ? callback(x) : x;
  ```

  and just not bother with the identity function. It may or may not be faster - I haven't benchmarked it. In any event, both approaches work just fine, so there's no need to change anything.
- If you do need an identity function, lo-dash has one built-in (`_.identity`). Saves you having to type it out.
- Lastly, if you want to be stringent, you might want to check whether `callback` is a function, instead of just doing "default if false'y". E.g.

  ```
  callback = _.isFunction(callback) ? callback : _.identity;
  // or just plain JS
  callback = typeof callback === 'function' ? callback : _.identity;
  ```

  Personally, I'd skip this, though. If people pass in something that's not a function, it's their bug to deal with. Besides, I'd rather have the code fail loudly than having it silently ignore my (faulty) `callback` argument and default to something else without telling me. Still, type-checking is an option, so I thought I'd mention it.

As for alternatives to the overall approach, I'd use `_.transform` (which is basically the same as `reduce`/`foldl` but aimed at objects)

```
var reverseMapFromMap = function(map, callback) {
  callback = callback || _.identity;
  return _.transform(map, function (memo, value, key) {
    key = callback(key);
    memo[value] || (memo[value] = []);
    memo[value].push(key);
  }, {});
}
```

And again for `mapFromReverseMap`

```
var mapFromReverseMap = function(reverseMap, callback) {
  callback = callback || _.identity;
  return _.transform(reverseMap, function (memo, keys, value) {
    _.forEach(keys, function (key) {
      memo[callback(key)] = value;
    });
  }, {});
};
```

Comment: Nice, but I think `callback = callback || _.identity` is better than `callback || (callback = _.identity)`. It's natural that way, no need to mess with it.

Comment: @janos Heh, hadn't even noticed that I changed that. It wasn't on purpose. And you're right, the version without the parens is more natural, though I personally don't mind either one. Still, I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks @Flambino! I employed some of your suggestions and have updated the question with the final code.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using built-in methods when you can. In this case I doesn't look like you need LoDash at all. You can use `Object.keys` and `reduce`:

```
var reverseMapFromMap = function(map, f) {
  return Object.keys(map).reduce(function(acc, k) {
    acc[map[k]] = (acc[map[k]] || []).concat((f || id)(k))
    return acc
  },{})
}

var mapFromReverseMap = function(rMap, f) {
  return Object.keys(rMap).reduce(function(acc, k) {
    rMap[k].forEach(function(x){acc[x] = (f || id)(k)})
    return acc
  },{})
}
```

I renamed `identity` to `id`, as it is a well known function in functional programming. I don't think it would create confusion, and lets you pass it in one liners easily, like shown above.

The above works with your example http://jsbin.com/cadig/1/edit. But I would recommend you reverse the arguments, so the callback comes first, and the receiver last, so it works better with composition.

Other than the missing braces in the `if` statement, I'd say your code looks pretty good. It is quite common though to use one or two letter variables in functional programming, as these transformations shall apply to many things in theory (polymorphism), and we only have a handful of objects. `f` clearly means "function" for example, and `x` is any value, where `k` is a "key". After getting used to these conventions, a line like:

```
rMap[k].forEach(function(x){acc[x] = (f || id)(k)})
```

seems faster to visually parse than:

```
rMap[key].forEach(function(value) {
  acc[value] = (callback || identity)(key)
})
```

Eventually your mind removes the `function` keyword, and you just see the transformation as it is. In ES6 this becomes even shorter, and calls for a concise one-liner:

```
rMap[k].forEach(x => acc[x] = (f || id)(k))
```

Comment: +1 for "native" functions. I consciously chose to stick to lo-dash in my answer, just for maximum compatibility. Besides, lo-dash will, I believe, just forward as much as possible to the native implementations, if available. Still, the more built-in functions you can use, the better.

Comment: On the contrary, [lodash is faster](http://jsperf.com/native-foreach-vs-lodash) than native for most cases. [This is primarily because it does not handle obscure use cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18884620/1412255).

Comment: Native solution didn't turn out so well, performance-wise. I have updated the question with some performance information.